# Error when using pickle for a discord bot | discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py, pickle

When trying to save my list of reactionrole objects with pickle it gives me the error `Command raised an exception: TypeError: cannot pickle 'TaskStepMethWrapper' object`.
I have not tried anything because I'm not sure what TaskStepMethWrapper is. Here's my code:

```py
@client.command()
async def reactionadd(ctx):
#  await ctx.send('Please give me the ID of the message you want to have a reactionrole on.')
#  msgid_var = await client.wait_for('message')
  await ctx.send('Please react with the emoji you want the reactionrole to use.')
  emoji_var = await client.wait_for('reaction_add')
#  await ctx.send('Please give me the ID of the role you want the reactionrole to give.')   
#  roleid_var = await client.wait_for('message')
  if not os.path.isfile('reactionrole.obj'):
    rrf = open('reactionrole.obj', 'xb')
    rrf.close()
  rrf = open('reactionrole.obj', 'rb+')
  if os.stat('reactionrole.obj').st_size == 0:
    rrobj = []
  else:
    rrobj = pickle.load(rrf)
  emoji_var = emoji_var[0]
  rrobj.append(reactionrole(749316751212150965, emoji_var, 749317419255857232))
  pickle.dump(rrobj, rrf)
  rrf.close()

class reactionrole:
    def __init__(self, msgid, emoji, roleid):
      self.msgid = msgid
      self.emoji = emoji
      self.roleid = roleid
```

SO, how to fix this error? should I go on with pickle or use another serialization technique? I could write to and parse a text file myself if needed.

Comment: did you use `Google` to check what is `TaskStepMethWrapper`? It shows that it part of `asyncio` and it unpickable. Probably it is in `emoji_var`. You should check what you have in `emoji_var` - `print(emoji_var)`, `print( type(emoji_var) )`. And see if you need it or if you can get values from `emoji_var` as `strings`, `list`, `dict`, `int` which are pickleabel

Comment: using `Google` I found similar problem [Why is python pickle failing to dump dictionaries in 3.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56213159/why-is-python-pickle-failing-to-dump-dictionaries-in-3-7) but also without solution.

Comment: @furas I'm not so sure about that because if the emoji is custom it'll give me an emoji object but if it's a normal global emoji then it's just a string with the emoji which I _have_ been using normal emojis.

Comment: it uses `await` and `async` so you may get some `asyncio` object instead of expected `string`

Comment: @furas I just ran type on emoji_var[0] and apparently it does give me an object. My bad I just made it a string and it works now thanks.

Comment: did you use `str()` to convert it?You could describe it in your answer and later you can mark you answer as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out emoji_var[0] is an object. Simply using `str()` to turn it into a string fixed this.